# find the bytecode of a contract during compilation

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle

Is there a solution to recover the complete bytecode (init + runtime) of a contract imported in solidity.
For example "bytes code = getBytecode (Escrow.sol)" and this would be replaced by bytecode during compilation? 
thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Surely it is immediate using Remix. Just a click on “detail”, then “bytecode”

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but I'm looking for something automatic in the code of solidity. for example in solidity when you do "new Escrow ()" you do not need to give the bytecode. the problem is that "new" will deploy the contract whereas I just want the bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible at build time, but you will need custom tools for this.

Lets assume you want to use byte code of contract `A` inside contract `B`.

At first compile contract `A` into byte code.  So you will have file `A.bin`.  Lets assume contents of this file is `0x6060604052604080519081...`.

Then you need to write a code that will take this byte code and convert it into Solidity file `A_bin.sol` looking like this:

```solidity
pragma solidity 0.5.7;

contract A_bin {
  bytes internal constant A_bytecode = abi.encodePacked(
    uint8 (0x60), uint8 (0x60), uint8 (0x60), uint8 (0x40),
    uint8 (0x52), uint8 (0x60), uint8 (0x40), uint8 (0x80),
    uint8 (0x51), uint8 (0x90), uint8 (0x81), ...);
}
```

You may write such code in Javascript of Python or whatever language you prefer.

Now in contract `B` you may include `A_bin.sol`, inherit contract `B` from `A_bin` and use `A_bytecode` where needed.